# Can you <run them by me> now

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-request, phrasal-verbs

Imagine you are teaching your child about a process that is made of a few stages, for example, the four-stage life cycle of a bug. After explaining each stage, you briefly go over them. And to check the child remembers the four stages, you ask them to say/name the four stages.

I wonder if you could say:

> Can you run them by me now?

If that is **not natural**, how would you ask the child to enumerate the four stages in non-marked, and informal registers?

The reason I am asking is that Cambridge states that

> to tell someone about something so that they can give their opinion about it

and Oxford gives

> (informal) to show sb sth or tell sb about an idea in order to see their reaction to it

While I heard the expression in situations where you would say it to ask someone to repeat what they have just said because you missed or misheard something as in:

**McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs**

> **run something by ( someone ) (again)**
>
> to explain something to someone again; to say something to someone
>   again.
>
> *• I didn't hear you. Please run that by me again. • Please run it by so we can all hear it.*

**Edit:**

Is it different from *Run that by me one more time*?

In the animated movie Planes 2013, Dusty says "run that by me one more time" because he wanted to hear the long unfamiliar instructions again. I mean there are no opinions or assessment, only instructions to follow.

> Maintain 1,000 feet. Intercept the 22 right localizer.
>
> You are cleared for the ILS 22, right approach.
>
> Roger. Heavy is sectored in behind you.
>
> **Dusty**: Run that by me one more time.
>
> Turn further left, heading 1-9-5. Maintain 1, 000
>
> **Dusty**: Never mind. I got it.

Answer (score 4):

You may be confusing your prepositions

> to run *something* by

is to review a piece of work for checking.

Your usage is understandable, but a better choice might be

> to run through

which has the meaning of to "go over" or to "repeat"

> Can you *run through* the four stages of an insect?

Alternatively, you might say

> Could you *review* the four stages of an insect?
>   Could you *repeat* the four stages of an insect?
>   Could you *go over* the four stages of an insect?

Comment: Thanks Peter. Your suggestion is adopted. But I guess I still want to clear the source of my confusion. I added it in the EDIT block in my post.

Comment: There is no difference except possibly one would add "one more time" after the first time *something* is run by you.

Answer (score 0):

According to merriam-webster.com, to run something by someone is to "to present to (as for evaluation)." So one would use the phrase when one wants an opinion or evaluation of a subject, not just for enumeration. In the example with the child, the parent is asking only for a list, so the expression would not be correct for the context. If it were my child, I'd simply ask her if she could name the four stages in order.

Comment: Thanks Michele. Would you like to update your answer after checking my post again.